# What audio file types (e.g., mp3, ogg) are supported by Mobile Safari and HTML5 iOS web apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, mobile, mobile-safari

There are many SO questions about playing audio files on Mobile Safari, but searching on SO and Google doesn't yield a comprehensive, updated list of audio files supported on Mobile Safari.

Anyone know what the current list of supported audio files is?

We're building a web app for the iPhone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the most recent list of supported media types, last updated in July 2011:

> Safari on the desktop supports any media the installed version of
>   QuickTime can play. This includes media encoded using codecs QuickTime
>   does not natively support, provided the codecs are installed on the
>   user’s computer as QuickTime codec components.
>
> Safari on iOS (including iPad) currently supports uncompressed WAV and
>   AIF audio, MP3 audio, and AAC-LC or HE-AAC audio. HE-AAC is the
>   preferred format.
>
> Safari on iOS (including iPad) currently supports MPEG-4 video
>   (Baseline profile) and QuickTime movies encoded with H.264 video
>   (Baseline profile) and one of the supported audio types.
>
> iPad and iPhone 3G and later support H.264 Baseline profile 3.1.
>   Earlier versions of iPhone support H.264 Baseline profile 3.0.

Found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1

Comment: Something that the above doesn't mention is that Safari on iOS also supports the Core Audio Format (CAF). This container supports Ogg Vorbis and Ogg Opus. So if you wanted to play Ogg Opus on Safari iOS, you need to use a .caf file and use the `audio/x-caf` mimetype.