# How to play ogg file in HTML in IPAD safari?

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, safari

I want play ogg file in IPAD safari.
ogg file have to contain in HTML file.
In Mac OS safari, ogg file play normally.
But, in iPad safari, ogg file didn't play.
How to solve this issue?

```
<body>
    <div class="gm4html5_div_class" id="gm4html5_div_id">
        <!-- Create the canvas element the game draws to -->
        <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480">
           <p>Your browser doesn't support HTML5 canvas.</p>
        </canvas>
    </div>

    <!-- Run the game code -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sndtest/index.js?FPLYB=1677165635"></script>
    <audio preload="auto" networkstate="0"><source src="sndtest/sound0.ogg" type="audio/ogg" codecs="vorbis"></audio>
    <audio preload="auto" networkstate="0"><source src="sndtest/sound1.ogg" type="audio/ogg" codecs="vorbis"></audio>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, 
you can't do that, the only files supported by Safari are the one that Quicktime can play, see :
[What audio file types (e.g., mp3, ogg) are supported by Mobile Safari and HTML5 iOS web apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780282/what-audio-file-types-e-g-mp3-ogg-are-supported-by-mobile-safari-and-html5)